# Dart: Declare function return type when function is an input

Tags: dart

So In my class constructor I want to accept a function as input so:

```
class foo() {
  final Function inpFunc;
  foo({this.inpFunc});
}
```

I want to only accept functions that return int but `final Function<int> inpFunc` is not valid

What should I do?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add return type and parameter details to be more specific.

`int Function()` for instance.

```dart
class Foo {
  final int Function() inpFunc;
  Foo(this.inpFunc);
}

main() {
  var foo = Foo(() => 42);

  print(foo.inpFunc());
}
```

Comment: Ack. Added some details.

Comment: Plz update to include argument types, as well! Eg: `final int Function(String) inpFunc` for a function that takes a String argument and returns an int. (The String should maybe be "What't the answer to life, the universe and everything?" or I dunno... )